# Border around whole website

Tags: border

I’m looking for a smart way to have a border around a whole website.

The problem is that I have a fixed div `.teaser-image` with a background  that should stretch over the whole viewport with the properties `width: 100%` and `height: 100%`, so I have to set `html`and `body` also to these values, otherwise the fixed div is only as high as its content.

When I add the border to the `body` it wraps only around the 100% height but doesn’t stretch around the whole site.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

http://jsfiddle.net/cJgBs/

HTML

```
<div class="teaser-image"></div>

<header>
    <h1>Headline</h1>
    <p>Some content</p>
</header>

<section>
    <h1>Headline</h1>
    <p>Some content</p>       
</section>        

<section>
    <h1>Headline</h1>
    <p>Some content</p>       
</section>
```

CSS

```
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    color: #fff;
}

body {
    border: 10px solid #000;
}

.teaser-image {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(http://www.joomlaworks.net/images/demos/galleries/abstract/7.jpg) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

header,
section {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** If you want the headers / sections to have the same height as the viewport, you can simply use [min-height: 100vh;](http://jsfiddle.net/cJgBs/2/)

I believe the main problem lies in setting min-height to 100% for headers and sections. This implies that each header / section should have a height greater than or equal to its parent's height. But the parent of headers and sections is the page body, so what you're essentially trying to do is make 3 child elements each have the same height as the containing element, which clearly isn't well defined.

One thing then that needs to be done is setting the header / section min-height to something constant (e.g. 300px). Another thing that needs to change is the html / body height. By setting it to 100% you prevent it from growing. Instead of height, you can use min-height here. Finally, for aesthetic reasons, you can add top:0; to your teaser-image class:

**CSS**

```
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    color: #fff;
}

body {
    border: 10px solid #000;
}

.teaser-image {
    top:0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(http://www.joomlaworks.net/images/demos/galleries/abstract/7.jpg) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

header,
section {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 300px;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}
```

The result of applying the above changes can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cJgBs/1/). Notice that the border now wraps the entire page. If you want the border to only wrap the current viewport, then you probably need something like [this](http://css-tricks.com/body-border/).